# Create array in bash dynamically

Tags: bash

I would like to create and fill an array dynamically but it doesn't work like this:

```
i=0
while true; do
    read input
    field[$i]=$input
    ((i++))
    echo {$field[$i]}  
done
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Aside from some minor issues, your code is fine.

Comment: It works like a simple variable. If I the input is test, it echo: {test[0]}

Comment: I don't see any `echo` there. You just have an infinite loop that appends an array and does nothing with it. Yes expanding `"$test"` is always equivalent to `"${test[0]}"` (even if `test` isn't an array).

Comment: I edited the post. I added echo {$field[$i]}

Comment: I saw the error is the $ symbol after the bracket

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The assignment is fine; the lookup is wrong:

```
echo "${field[$i]}"
```

Answer (score 20):

Try something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
field=()
while read -r input ; do
    field+=("$input")
done
echo Num items: ${#field[@]}
echo Data: ${field[@]}
```

It stops reading when no more input is available (end of file, `^D` in the keyboard), then prints the number of elements read and the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

```
i= field=()
while :; do
    read -r 'field[i++]'
done
```

Is one way. `mapfile` is another. Or any of [these](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). However what you've posted is valid.